# JavaScript how to evaluate type of variable and return sum of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, typeof

So I am trying to write a function that evaluates an array and only output the sum of all number variables from the array. For example, if I enter the array [1,2,3,"chunky bacon", 5, false], it will only adds up 1,2,3,and 5, thus return 11.
Here is what I wrote:

```
var sum = function(num) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (typeof i == "number") {
            total += num[i];
        };
    };
    console.log(total);
}
```

However when I tested it in my console with [1,2,3,"chunky bacon", 5, false], it will return

> 6chunky bacon5false

So my question is 
1)How would I make the loop don't stop when it runs into a none number element, so in the above example it will continue to add 6 with 5? 
2)How would I make it stop printing the none number elements? I don't know why it prints it out since I only said console.log(total).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: myArray.filter(Number).reduce(sum)

Comment: @dandavis: If only JavaScript had a `sum` global. I guess `.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b }, 0)` works too.

Comment: I think you meant `if (typeof num[i] == "number") {`. In the loop, `i` (the incremented index) will always be a number. You seem to want to check the value in the array, which is `num[i]`

Comment: yeah, i pray every night for Math.sum and Math.diff so we can do fast native math on arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(typeof i == "number") is always a number because "i" is your loop counter. You should use

```
if (typeof num[i] == "number")
```

(snippet not tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by checking isNaN against the array value.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, "chunky bacon", 5, false];

var sum = function(arr) {
    var a = 0;
    var b = arr.length;
    for ( c = 0; c < b; c++ ) {
        if ( !isNaN(arr[c]) ) {
            a += arr[c];
        }
    }    
    return a;
}

console.log(sum(array));
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KA827/1/

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't treat the case where an element is the empty string (`""`) correctly. It will pass the check and make the sum variable into a string and begin concatenating the numbers and other elements that don't convert to NaN. For instance, the array:
`var array = [1, "", "chunky bacon", 2, false];`
Will print `12false` instead of `3`;